# How to enable migration on codefirst model

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I just have created my first codefirst model and want to enable migrations.

This is part of my Model code:

```
namespace Layers.Data_Access_Layer.CodeFirst.Entities
{
     public partial class MyModel : DbContext
    {
        public MyModel()
            : base("name =CodeFirstModel")
        {

        }
 public virtual DbSet<tblBaseInfo> tblBaseInfo { get; set; }
.
.
.

    }
}
```

I just wrote the following instruction :

```
Enable-Migrations -CodeFirstModel Layers.Data_Access_Layer.CodeFirst.Entities
```

and  unfortunately I received the following error:

> Enable-Migrations: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'CodeFirstModel'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Enable-Migrations CodeFirstModel Layers.Data_Access_Layer.CodeFi ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingException
>
> ### + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Enable-Migrations

***Please help me to handle my error with enabling migration.***

I have an extra question: when I enable migrations in my project, does it automatically add a table to SQL server (dbo.__migrationHistory) ??

Comment: Is this EF or EF Core?

Comment: Entity framework (EF)

Comment: This link can help you http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: That is not the proper syntax to enable-migrations. See [here](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/). You may need to add parameters if your context is in a separate project. It takes 3 steps to actually update your database (unless automatic migrations are enabled): 1) enable-migrations, 2) add-migration MyChanges 3) update-database.